# start parachain collator node encounter relay chain block sync problem

Tags: parachain

I make a parachain rococo test net practice following [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/acquire-a-testnet-slot/). But I encounter issue after start collator node:

```
[Relaychain] cannot query the runtime API version: UnknownBlock: State already discarded for 0xb5ca6f77cde65f43b7dc8e2f551b6ff36327126392d08a99409531df0e7c0e1c
```

after a while, the relay chain block sync is not working. the detail logs are bellow:

```
2023-02-02 14:35:23.179  INFO main sc_cli::runner: Parachain Collator Template    
2023-02-02 14:35:23.180  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ✌️  version 0.1.0-677a1a238a9    
2023-02-02 14:35:23.180  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ❤️  by Anonymous, 2020-2023    
2023-02-02 14:35:23.180  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Chain specification: Bill Parachain    
2023-02-02 14:35:23.180  INFO main sc_cli::runner:   Node name: undesirable-hole-5658    
2023-02-02 14:35:23.180  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-02-02 14:35:23.180  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Database: RocksDb at data/chains/billp/db/full    
2023-02-02 14:35:23.180  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ⛓  Native runtime: template-parachain-1 (template-parachain-0.tx1.au1)    
2023-02-02 14:35:27.753  INFO main parachain_template_node::command: Parachain id: Id(4221)    
2023-02-02 14:35:27.753  INFO main parachain_template_node::command: Parachain Account: 5Ec4AhPCKCoMsQQ12wDRHFXGije6QtbrrQBNp8HtLMhwWttY    
2023-02-02 14:35:27.753  INFO main parachain_template_node::command: Parachain genesis state: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000083eaa934f8e151ec6bffc023f7c16ea71267b0c807be2ca1f19754c7b44ff1d703170a2e7597b7b7e3d84c05391d139a62b157e78786d8c082f29dcf4c11131400    
2023-02-02 14:35:27.753  INFO main parachain_template_node::command: Is collating: yes    
2023-02-02 14:35:28.530  INFO main sc_service::client::client: [Parachain]  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0x83ea…f1d7, header-hash: 0x76d3…0131)    
2023-02-02 14:35:28.533 DEBUG main parachain: [Parachain] Restoring chain level monitor from last finalized block: 0 0x76d3…0131    
2023-02-02 14:35:28.534 DEBUG main parachain: [Parachain] Restored chain level monitor up to height 1    
2023-02-02 14:35:29.842  INFO main sc_service::client::client: [Relaychain]  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0x8ad9…f0da, header-hash: 0x6408…063e)    
2023-02-02 14:35:29.860 DEBUG main parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Using dispute aware relay-chain selection algorithm
2023-02-02 14:35:29.865  INFO main grandpa: [Relaychain]  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.    
2023-02-02 14:35:30.368  INFO main babe: [Relaychain]  Creating empty BABE epoch changes on what appears to be first startup.  
...
2023-02-02 14:35:35.549  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing, target=#3939536 (10 peers), best: #448 (0x12f3…93e2), finalized #0 (0x6408…063e), ⬇ 375.8kiB/s ⬆ 20.5kiB/s    
2023-02-02 14:35:35.568 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: [Relaychain] Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1675229735 min_ts=0 max_ts=0
2023-02-02 14:35:35.604  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x76d3…0131), finalized #0 (0x76d3…0131), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2023-02-02 14:35:37.622 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Block finalized block_hash=0x18ddf1f12cc86abeb357487531608a8edd98feeb03b6b7545382465122064b3c block_number=512
2023-02-02 14:35:37.622 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Removing relay parent because our view changed. relay_parent=0x6408de7737c59c238890533af25896a2c20608d8b380bb01029acb392781063e
2023-02-02 14:35:39.452 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Block finalized block_hash=0xa360b6bb5981fc1a175742ece7e1a6be3a579edfd6edfc8a13161c7a218ff3d4 block_number=1024
2023-02-02 14:35:39.455  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::runtime-api: [Relaychain] cannot query the runtime API version: UnknownBlock: State already discarded for 0xb5ca6f77cde65f43b7dc8e2f551b6ff36327126392d08a99409531df0e7c0e1c
2023-02-02 14:35:39.455 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::availability-store: [Relaychain] err=RuntimeApi(NotSupported { runtime_api_name: "candidate_events" })
2023-02-02 14:35:39.671  WARN tokio-runtime-worker runtime::inclusion-inherent: [Relaychain] CurrentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2023-02-02 14:35:39.690 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Block finalized block_hash=0xf274389771b7e381cb75b8816c2f202621ce31e68e36f0c3b2a82a856f612403 block_number=1179
2023-02-02 14:35:39.695  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::runtime-api: [Relaychain] cannot query the runtime API version: UnknownBlock: State already discarded for 0xb5ca6f77cde65f43b7dc8e2f551b6ff36327126392d08a99409531df0e7c0e1c
2023-02-02 14:35:39.695 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::availability-store: [Relaychain] err=RuntimeApi(NotSupported { runtime_api_name: "candidate_events" })
2023-02-02 14:35:40.384 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: [Relaychain] Block finalized block_hash=0xef50450c80bce9f24beba006cb0404d40866241e88a90751bc9c7a037e6fe968 block_number=1536
2023-02-02 14:35:40.391 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::availability-store: [Relaychain] err=RuntimeApi(NotSupported { runtime_api_name: "candidate_events" })
2023-02-02 14:35:40.549  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 235.6 bps, target=#3939537 (40 peers), best: #1626 (0xb55f…ec06), finalized #1536 (0xef50…e968), ⬇ 580.1kiB/s ⬆ 73.2kiB/s    
...
2023-02-02 14:36:00.549  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 38.4 bps, target=#3939537 (40 peers), best: #5120 (0x141b…4f75), finalized #5120 (0x141b…4f75), ⬇ 781.7kiB/s ⬆ 90.2kiB/s    
...
2023-02-02 14:36:05.550  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 243.2 bps, target=#3939537 (40 peers), best: #6336 (0x1650…9ccd), finalized #6144 (0x7f10…b7d7), ⬇ 346.3kiB/s ⬆ 78.1kiB/s
...
2023-02-02 14:36:10.550  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#3939537 (40 peers), best: #6336 (0x1650…9ccd), finalized #6144 (0x7f10…b7d7), ⬇ 373.5kiB/s ⬆ 45.1kiB/s
```

I'm using the latest version (main branch, commit: 677a1a238a9592d0c8f1f0a4b7477b031da76c20) of [substrate-parachain-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template).
Does anyone encounter such a problem?
Thanks!

Comment: What's your polkadot node version?

Comment: Thank your reply:) , the node\Cargo.toml file show "release-v0.9.37", "polkadot-v0.9.37"

Comment: run command:
./target/release/parachain-template-node \
--collator \
--chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json \
--base-path data \
--port 50333 \
--ws-port 8855 \
-lparachain=debug \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain rococo \
--port 50343 \
--ws-port 9988

Comment: Did you try and purge your chain? Running with a specific base path can corrupt things when testing things out

Comment: @DanShields Yes, I have tried this many times. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: I have seen the exact same error after upgrading based on polkadot-v0.9.37. My observation is the finalization proceeds for the relay chain even after this error is repeatedly thrown. However my own issue is it gets stuck when it stats to finalize the parachain with no good logs to indicate anything.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with the same message: cannot query the runtime API version: UnknownBlock: State already discarded for 0xb5ca6f77cde65f43b7dc8e2f551b6ff36327126392d08a99409531df0e7c0e1c. Have someone figured what the possible reason could be?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.